# Why did Spark standalone Worker node-1 terminate after RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM?

Tags: apache-spark, sigterm, apache-spark-standalone

Note: This error was thrown before the components were executed by spark.

Logs
Worker Node1:

```
17/05/18 23:12:52 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://spark-master-1.com:7077  
17/05/18 23:58:41 ERROR Worker: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

Master Node:

```
17/05/18 23:12:52 INFO Master: Registering worker spark-worker-1com:56056 with 2 cores, 14.5 GB RAM
17/05/18 23:14:20 INFO Master: Registering worker spark-worker-2.com:53986 with 2 cores, 14.5 GB RAM
17/05/18 23:59:42 WARN Master: Removing spark-worker-1com-56056 because we got no heartbeat in 60 seconds
17/05/18 23:59:42 INFO Master: Removing spark-worker-2.com:56056
17/05/19 00:00:03 ERROR Master: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

Worker Node2:

```
17/05/18 23:14:20 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://spark-master-node-2.com:7077
17/05/18 23:59:40 ERROR Worker: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** I think someone has explicitly called `kill` command or `sbin/stop-worker.sh`.

"RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM" is reported by a [shutdown hook](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/SignalUtils.scala#L38-L49) to log `TERM`, `HUP`, `INT` signals on UNIX-like systems:

```
  /** Register a signal handler to log signals on UNIX-like systems. */
  def registerLogger(log: Logger): Unit = synchronized {
    if (!loggerRegistered) {
      Seq("TERM", "HUP", "INT").foreach { sig =>
        SignalUtils.register(sig) {
          log.error("RECEIVED SIGNAL " + sig)
          false
        }
      }
      loggerRegistered = true
    }
  }
```

In your case it means that the process received [SIGTERM](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) to stop itself:

> The SIGTERM signal is a generic signal used to cause program termination. Unlike SIGKILL, this signal can be blocked, handled, and ignored. It is the normal way to politely ask a program to terminate.

That's what is sent when you execute `KILL` or use `./sbin/stop-master.sh` or `./sbin/stop-worker.sh` shell scripts that in turn call `sbin/spark-daemon.sh` with `stop` command that [kills a JVM process for a master or a worker](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sbin/spark-daemon.sh#L209):

```
kill "$TARGET_ID" && rm -f "$pid"
```